# Alternative to Package Foundry? (PHP app installation)

Tags: php, installation

I'm looking for an alternative to [Package Foundry](http://www.ioncube.com/ipf/). It doesn't have to be - and I'm sure won't be - free or anything like that.

It also needs to be able to create a configuration file, which asks for their database details and such. Without that, it's just an automated FTP app, which is of limited use.

Are there any alternatives which might be able to automate the uploading and then just request some info from the user, and then perform a check to make sure they're valid?

Answer (score 1):

[**NSIS** (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is a professional open source system to create Windows installers. It is designed to be as small and flexible as possible and is therefore very suitable for internet distribution.

Or distribute your application via a **[PEAR channel](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0308_set_up_your_own_pear_channel.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/).  It's a free, open source installer that can do everything you need.  Drop by the forums if you need some help getting started with your installer, and I'll be glad to show you how to do what you want here.  It's actually been done by many before, so it's not all that hard. :)

Comment: I've only briefly looked at this, but thanks. It looks great - are you sure it can install web applications though?

Comment: I have many users who are already using it as such.  What is special about the web application that you want to install?  You can easily create configuration files, you can use FTP or HTTP from within the installer to pull down files.  The trickiest thing I can think about a web app is just making sure things get installed in the right place, and if you can't figure that out on your own, you can always ask the user where they want it. :)